# Spring Security: LDAP Authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to use spring security ldap authentication in my web application.On login page i will ask user to enter his/her username and password. Now using this credentials if application is able to connect to the ldap server then user is valid user and i will show him/her home page. but if credentials are wrong then i have to redirect to the login page with error message.

Can anyone tell me how can i achieve this using spring security ldap authentication.

My Spring-security.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

    <http pattern="/css/**" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/images/**" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/index.jsp" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/js/**" security="none" />

    <http use-expressions="false">
        <csrf disabled="true" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <form-login login-page='/index.jsp' login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" 
            username-parameter="username" 
            password-parameter="password" 
            default-target-url='/login.do'
            authentication-failure-url="/index.jsp?error=1"
            always-use-default-target='true' />
        <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" />
        <http-basic />
    </http>


    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider ref="authProvider"></authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="authProvider" class="com.abc.web.security.CustomAuthentication" />

    <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
</beans:beans>
```

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ldap.html

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/